How do I securely point a subdomain from Hostinger to a CloudFlare page?
I have a website hosted on Hostinger, with the domain managed on Hostinger as well.
I've built a seperate page which I am hosting on CloudFlare Pages that I would like to make accessible via a subdomain.
I want to the DNS records of the domain in Hostinger and added a new CNAME record, with the name being my desired subdomain (e.g. "subdomain", not the entire address).
For the value of "Points to" I've entered the address of my cloudflare page (e.g. "my-new-page.pages.dev") and I've left TTL as the default of 14400.
It's been a few hours and when I try to access it now it says
This site can’t provide a secure connection
subdomain.mydomain.org uses an unsupported protocol.
Have I done things properly and I just need to wait longer? Or did I not configure it properly?
In the extra details it says
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

Did you follow the instructions here? https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/configuration/custom-domains/

@MarkB Nope but I did just now and it works! Thank you for pointing me the right direction

Ensure your Cloudflare Pages site has an active SSL certificate, verify the CNAME record is proxied through Cloudflare (orange cloud enabled), and check DNS propagation in Hostinger to confirm the subdomain is correctly linked.
